# how do you connect the virtual keys so that they print to the text field on top?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

i set up the format of the hebrew keyboard but cant figure out how to get the keys to work so that what you type is shown in the text field on top. "keyboard" contains a function for each key. in theory it was supposed to be called to print each key. there is probably  a more efficient way of doing this but this is my first gui so i dont really know what to do and couldnt find a solution online that fit this case specificaly.

```
    import wx
    calc=wx.App()
    win=wx.Frame(None, title='gematria calculator', size=(1400,700), pos=(0,0))
    import keyboard  #contains functions for each key (eg- keyboard.aleph() should print letter aleph to the text field)

    textfield=wx.TextCtrl(win, pos=(50,25), size=(1100,150))   #where everything should print to
    enter=wx.Button(win, label='enter', pos=(1175,25), size=(200,150))

    '''keys'''
    space=wx.Button(win, label='space', pos=(400,500), size=(600,100))
    aleph=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d0', pos=(500,200), size=(100,100))
    bet=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d1', pos=(450,400), size=(100,100))
    gimel=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d2', pos=(400,300), size=(100,100))
    dallet=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d3', pos=(300,300), size=(100,100))
    hey=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d4', pos=(550,400), size=(100,100))
    vav=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d5', pos=(700,200), size=(100,100))
    zayen=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d6', pos=(250,400), size=(100,100))
    chet=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d7', pos=(800,300), size=(100,100))
    tet=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d8', pos=(600,200), size=(100,100))
    yud=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05d9', pos=(700,300), size=(100,100))
    kaf_s=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05da', pos=(1000,300), size=(100,100))
    kaf=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05db', pos=(500,300), size=(100,100))
    lammed=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05dc', pos=(900,300), size=(100,100))
    mem_s=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05dd', pos=(900,200), size=(100,100))
    mem=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05de', pos=(750,400), size=(100,100))
    nun_s=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05df', pos=(800,200), size=(100,100))
    nun=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e0', pos=(650,400), size=(100,100))
    samech=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e1', pos=(350,400), size=(100,100))
    ayin=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e2', pos=(600,300), size=(100,100))
    pey_s=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e3', pos=(1100,300), size=(100,100))
    pey=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e4', pos=(1000,200), size=(100,100))
    tsadi_s=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e5', pos=(1050,400), size=(100,100))
    tsadi=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e6', pos=(850,400), size=(100,100))
    kuf=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e7', pos=(300,200), size=(100,100))
    resh=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e8', pos=(400,200), size=(100,100))
    shin=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05e9', pos=(200,300), size=(100,100))
    tuf=wx.Button(win, label=u'\u05ea', pos=(950,400), size=(100,100))


    win.Show()
    calc.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to catch EVT_KEY_DOWN and do your string substitution in that event handler. So when you catch a letter, you translate it into the appropriate Hebrew character and do something like this:

```
self.myTextCtrl.AppendText(someHebrewLetter)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without knowing exactly what the functions in the `keyboard` module do, but I'll assume they just append the corresponding symbols to the text field.

With so many similar buttons, it's probably simplest to use wx IDs for each key, and avoid the tedium of creating many similar variables and functions. Similarly, if each function in the `keyboard` module does pretty much the same thing, that can also be factored out.

So it's probably easiest to put all the keyboard info in a configuration 'variable', and iterate over that when building the controls.

```
import wx

# Had to comment this out
#import keyboard  #contains functions for each key (eg- keyboard.aleph() should print letter aleph to the text field)

# Keyboard layout (function_name, button_label, text_to_add, position, size)
KEYBOARD_LAYOUT = \
(
    ('space',   u'space',   u' ',       (400,500),  (600,100)),
    ('aleph',   u'\u05d0',  u'\u05d0',  (500,200),  (100,100)),
    ('bet',     u'\u05d1',  u'\u05d1',  (450,400),  (100,100)),
    ('gimel',   u'\u05d2',  u'\u05d2',  (400,300),  (100,100)),
    ('dallet',  u'\u05d3',  u'\u05d3',  (300,300),  (100,100)),
    ('hey',     u'\u05d4',  u'\u05d4',  (550,400),  (100,100)),
    ('vav',     u'\u05d5',  u'\u05d5',  (700,200),  (100,100)),
    ('zayen',   u'\u05d6',  u'\u05d6',  (250,400),  (100,100)),
    ('chet',    u'\u05d7',  u'\u05d7',  (800,300),  (100,100)),
    ('tet',     u'\u05d8',  u'\u05d8',  (600,200),  (100,100)),
    ('yud',     u'\u05d9',  u'\u05d9',  (700,300),  (100,100)),
    ('kaf_s',   u'\u05da',  u'\u05da',  (1000,300), (100,100)),
    ('kaf',     u'\u05db',  u'\u05db',  (500,300),  (100,100)),
    ('lammed',  u'\u05dc',  u'\u05dc',  (900,300),  (100,100)),
    ('mem_s',   u'\u05dd',  u'\u05dd',  (900,200),  (100,100)),
    ('mem',     u'\u05de',  u'\u05de',  (750,400),  (100,100)),
    ('nun_s',   u'\u05df',  u'\u05df',  (800,200),  (100,100)),
    ('nun',     u'\u05e0',  u'\u05e0',  (650,400),  (100,100)),
    ('samech',  u'\u05e1',  u'\u05e1',  (350,400),  (100,100)),
    ('ayin',    u'\u05e2',  u'\u05e2',  (600,300),  (100,100)),
    ('pey_s',   u'\u05e3',  u'\u05e3',  (1100,300), (100,100)),
    ('pey',     u'\u05e4',  u'\u05e4',  (1000,200), (100,100)),
    ('tsadi_s', u'\u05e5',  u'\u05e5',  (1050,400), (100,100)),
    ('tsadi',   u'\u05e6',  u'\u05e6',  (850,400),  (100,100)),
    ('kuf',     u'\u05e7',  u'\u05e7',  (300,200),  (100,100)),
    ('resh',    u'\u05e8',  u'\u05e8',  (400,200),  (100,100)),
    ('shin',    u'\u05e9',  u'\u05e9',  (200,300),  (100,100)),
    ('tuf',     u'\u05ea',  u'\u05ea',  (950,400),  (100,100))
)


# Setup
calc = wx.App()
win = wx.Frame(None, title='gematria calculator', size=(1400,700), pos=(0,0))

# Add non-keyboard controls
textfield = wx.TextCtrl(win, pos=(50,25), size=(1100,150))   #where everything should print to

# Create dictionary to store wx ID to key mapping
keyboard_controls = {}

# Add keyboard controls
for function_name, button_label, text_to_add, position, size in KEYBOARD_LAYOUT:

    # Create a new wx ID
    key_id = wx.NewId()

    # Create the button
    button = wx.Button(win, id=key_id, label=button_label, pos=position, size=size)

    # Add mapping from key_id to (function_name, text_to_add) to dictionary
    keyboard_controls[key_id] = (function_name, text_to_add)

# Add enter button
key_id = wx.NewId()
enter = wx.Button(win, id=key_id, label='enter', pos=(1175,25), size=(200,150))
keyboard_controls[key_id] = (None, None)

# Define a callback for the keys
def on_key_pressed(event):

    # Look up the key info from the dictionary we made earlier
    key_id = event.GetId()
    try:
        function_name, text_to_add = keyboard_controls[key_id]
    except KeyError:
        # Indicates an ID we aren't handling, so pass it on
        event.Skip()
        return

    # Special case for enter key
    if function_name is None:
        wx.MessageBox('You clicked enter', 'Information', wx.ICON_INFORMATION|wx.OK)
        return

    # As this point we can either call the function from the keyboard module
    #function = getattr(keyboard, function_name)
    #function()

    # ...or just add the text directly
    textfield.AppendText(text_to_add)

# Now we can bind the event handler to the frame
win.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, on_key_pressed)

# Now run the app
win.Show()
calc.MainLoop()
```

Note that dictionary `keyboard_controls` in that code stores both the function name, and the text to add, but you only need one or the other, depending on which is more appropriate.